# Is it possible to append templates in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I'm trying to display 2 views on the same page (both from different apps).

I've imported the views into a third app which I want to use to put the 2 files together. At the moment I'm able to show 1 of the 2 apps. I'm retrieving the views of the app like this:

```
def bar(request):
    # Get the template
    template = loader.get_template('topbar.html')

    #render the template and store the outcome in 'render'
    render = template.render({}, request)

    #return the rendered template
    return render
```

after this I can get this view from another app like this:

```
render = bar(request)
return HttpResponse(render)
```

This works and the html file is showing nicely but now I want to append the second view (which can be requested in the same way) to the first one. Is this possible? Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: You may want to simply have an `{% include 'other_template.html' %}` tag in the template if that fits your use case. Or have a third template that includes both.

Comment: does that work if I need to interact with the database in that template?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What do you need from the database and why not just grab it in that view? Generally speaking, you don't perform queries from templates. Django is pretty opinionated about keeping those ideas separated. In general, perform queries in views and pass them into the context.

Comment: yes i'm doing that in the view... that's why i'm asking if that will still work when just adding the 'other_template.html'

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. If I'm understanding you right: yes, the context would be available to included templates defaultly. You can also override values. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use an [*Include*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag.

Suppose you have `'myapp/my_template.html'` and you want to include the entire contents of  `'other_app/other_template.html'` right after it. You can simply add the following to the end of your `my_template.html` template:

```
{% include 'other_app/other_template.html' %}
```

This renders the included template using the current context. That is to say: variables from the current template are available to the included template.

Comment: how would this work if I have html saved in a string?

Answer (score 0):

First point: in your example, `bar()` is not a proper view - it returns a unicode string (result of rendering a template), not an `HttpResponse`, so you can *not* use it as a view.

Second point: as I mentionned above, what `bar()` returns is just a plain unicode string. If you have a function `foo()` which renders another template and returns the result (another unicode string), you can *of course* concatenate those two strings - actually, the fact you used templates to build those two strings is totally irrelevant.

Now wether concatenating those two strings will yield valid html (assuming you use the templates to generate html) is another question. Both templates are rendered separately and chances are both were designed to generate a full html document, so you will probably end up with the concatenation of two html documents, which does not result in a valid html document.

So to answer your questions:

> Is this possible?

Yes, obviously.

> Am I doing it the right way?

Obviously not. Actually, the very first sentence of your question:

> I'm trying to display 2 views on the same page

shows a lack of understanding of what Django views are. A Django view is a callable that takes a request (HttpRequest) as input and returns a response (HttpResponse) as output. So "displaying two view on a page" just doesn't make sense - actually even "displaying a view" don't make sense in itself, you don't "display" a view (the http client can eventually "display" the http response itself, but the http response is not the view).

As to "what would be the right way to solve your problem", well the only sensible answer is "it depends" - first we don't have enough details (but "enough" might actually be "too much for a SO question"), and then there are probably more than one "correct" solution, each with it's pros and cons.

Comment: I've appended the 2 templates into one string, how would I go about displaying it on a html page?

Comment: Once again, "displaying it on a html page" doesn't mean anything. If what you want is to return this as the body of a http response, all you have to do is to create a `HttpResponse` instance with your concatenated html as content and return this response from your view - nothing special here, plain standard django stuff.

Comment: Wait... I have 2 html files ´bar´ and ´foo´ generated from templates and a ´base.html´ template which should take these other 2 files and display them one after another... This template is then send back in the HttpResponse, right? In this case how would I go about displaying ´bar´ and ´foo´ on that ´base.html´ file?